# How do i continue translate transition?

Tags: javafx, css-transitions, nodes

I want to make the node go further instead of starting from initial coordinates and going a certain distance can anyone help me?

```
public void sky(Node node, double xDest, double yDest) {

        TranslateTransition tTrans = new TranslateTransition(
                Duration.millis(4000), node);
        tTrans.setFromX(0);
        tTrans.setFromY(0);
        tTrans.setToY(yDest);
        tTrans.setToX(xDest);
        tTrans.setRate(2);
        tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        tTrans.play();
    }
```

The method above moves a node with xDest and yDest.

> xDest = x coordinate and yDest = y coordinate

If the initial coordinates are `100, 100` and `xDest = 50 and yDest = 50` then when i press the button the node will go to 150, 150 but if i press the button again the animation shows the node starting from 100, 100 and going to 150, 150. I want it to go to 200, 200 at second mouse click, any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `byX` and `byY` properties instead of the `toX` and `toY` properties:

```
public void sky(Node node, double deltaX, double deltaY) {

    TranslateTransition tTrans = new TranslateTransition(
            Duration.millis(4000), node);
    tTrans.setFromX(node.getTranslateX());
    tTrans.setFromY(node.getTranslateY());
    tTrans.setByY(deltaY);
    tTrans.setByX(deltaX);
    tTrans.setRate(2);
    tTrans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    tTrans.play();
}
```

Now each time you call this with `deltaX=50` and `deltaY=50` it will translate it by an additional 50 pixels along both axes.